# The server tag is not well formed using runat=server

Tags: asp.net

I am getting an error of "The server tag is not well formed" but I can't seem to figure out how to fix this exactly. The line it's breaking on is below.

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSoftware" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("Software")%>'<%# Eval("Software").ToString() == "Spotlight" ? " checked='checked'" : "" %>><%# Eval("Software") %><br />
```

I tried removing runat="server" and the page is displayed correctly but when I submit the form the repeater is on no data is stored. In my code behind I am using a control to concatenate the selections in my repeater but even when I select other checkboxes, that data is not getting into the database.

This worked before I tried to auto select the "Spotlight" checkbox on page load so it's something in this line of code that is causing the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `<asp:Checkbox id="checkboxSoftware" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Software")%>' Checked='<%# Eval("Software").ToString() == "Spotlight" %>'>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this deleted my labels for all checkboxes and still didn't record the selection in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxSoftware" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("Software")%>' checked='<%# Eval("Software").ToString() == "Spotlight" %>' /><%# Eval("Software") %>
```

I don't think you can evaluate values inside of a server tag unless you are setting an attribute and you had missed the closing tag for the input element.

Comment: You have helped with the checkbox auto selecting which is great but when I submit it still isn't getting to the database.

Comment: Actually after looking at your solution, the data did come in correctly. I was missing a piece of the code but when I put it back in it worked. Thanks for all your help.